# npm install --save express issuing a proxy error on OSX Yosemite

Tags: node.js, command-line, proxy, npm

> I have Node(v4.1.0) and npm(2.14.3) both installed but when I try to enter the commmand:

```
npm install --save express
```

> I receive the following error message:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "--save" "express"
npm ERR! node v4.1.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.3
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo

npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND host host:80
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Christopher_Pelnar/npm-debug.log
```

> Anybody have any experiences or ideas for dealing with this issue? I have tried configuring proxy settings using:

```
npm config set registry=http://registry.npmjs.org
```

> But that did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Adding the following code into the command line resolved the issue:

```
npm config set proxy=http://registry.npmjs.org
```

> Changing "registry" => "proxy" was the difference.